# Android -- Parsing an image from uri with hashmap gives me error

Tags: java, android, json, image, parsing

I need to parse the json output in my xml. Parsing is done but the image is not seen in the xml. Android log says this -

```
12-22 14:26:34.472: I/System.out(6037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: "base_url"/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-6175010166.jpg
```

Is there anything wrong in my below code can any body suggest me ?

```
HashMap<String, String> listview = new HashMap<String, String>();
String title = "";
String teaser="";
String createdon = "";
String profile_image = "";      
try {
  title = jListview.getString("title");
  teaser = jListview.getString("teaser");
  createdon = jListview.getString("created");
  profile_image = jListview.getString("profile_image");
  listview.put("title", title);
  listview.put("teaser", teaser);
  listview.put("created", createdon);
  listview.put("profile_image", profile_image);
  //listview.put("profile_image", picture);
} catch (JSONException e) { 
  System.out.println( "Bad Error" + e.toString());
  e.printStackTrace();
} 
return listview;
```

This is my main activity code where iam showing the result

```
         try{
        /** Getting the parsed data as a List construct */
            lists = listJsonParser.parse(obj);
            int imageCount = lists.size();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception Main",e.toString());
        }          

        /** Keys used in Hashmap */
        String[] from = { "title","teaser","created","profile_image"};

        /** Ids of views in listview_layout */
        int[] to = { R.id.title,R.id.teaser,R.id.createdon,R.id.list_image};

        /** Instantiating an adapter to store each items
        *  R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
        */
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), countries, R.layout.home_layout, from, to);  

        return adapter;

            LoGcat:12-22 14:26:34.382: I/System.out(6037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri:
```

Comment: Can you post your code some more and even full logcat? What you have pasted is the general adding and getting of the values. Such information is not enough to answer for others.

Comment: try using base baseadapter listview..

Answer (score 0):

you can not set Direct web url to `ImageView` for setting ImageView src.  you first create an custom Adapter by extending `BaseAdapter` for ListView and in getView you will need to first download image from Url as Bitmap and then set it to ImageView as:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,
                                 ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) 
                                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.
                                     inflate(R.layout.layout_row, null);
         }

        Bitmap test = getbitpam(maptemp.get("profile_image"));
        imgview=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_list);
        imgview.setImageBitmap(test);
        return convertView;
    }
}
//get image from server 
public  Bitmap getbitpam(String url) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(), IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        //options.inSampleSize = 1;

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length,options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}


}
```

Comment: I was talking about your hat. your last one was better(Moshi Moshi). I love that.

Answer (score 0):

your Error says Below:

```
12-22 14:26:34.472: I/System.out(6037): resolveUri failed on bad bitmap uri: "base_url"/sites/default/files/pictures/picture-6175010166.jpg
```

you need to download the image and then set it as bitmap. [HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html) is one of the many examples.